# Python WebDriver AttributeError: LoginPage instance has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have read a few tutorials on Python Selenium Webdriver Page Object model as I have to automate the gui tests using Selenium with Python.

To start off with I am trying to write a Login Page class and a LoginMainTest class.  I am getting the following error when i run the code.

AttributeError: LoginPage instance has no attribute 'driver'

I think i have to specify the selenium driver where i instantiate the LoginPage 
 e.g. on this line log_in = LoginPage.LoginPage()

I need some help please.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python projects\unitTest_sample - Modifying into Page Object\LoginMainTest.py", line 11, in test_valid_login
log_in = LoginPage.LoginPage()
File "E:\unitTest_sample - Modifying into Page Object\LoginPage.py", line 20, in __init__
emailFieldElement  = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.emailFieldID)
AttributeError: LoginPage instance has no attribute 'driver'
```

My LoginMainTest.py class is as follows:

```
import LoginPage
import unittest

class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_valid_login(self):
    log_in = LoginPage.LoginPage()
    log_in.userLogin_valid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

My Login.py class is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

class LoginPage():

Username            = "test1"
password            = "Test"
emailFieldID        = "email"
passFieldID         = "pass"
loginButtonXpath    = "//input[@value='log in']"
logo_xpath          = "//a[contains(@href, 'logo')])[1]"

def setup(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://www.testaaa.com")

def __init__(self):
    emailFieldElement  = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.emailFieldID)
    passFieldElement   = self.driver. find_element_by_id(self.passFieldID)
    loginFieldElement  =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.loginButtonXpath)

def userLogin_valid(self):
    self.emailFieldElement.clear()
    self.emailFieldElement.send_keys(self.Username)
    self.passFieldElement.clear()
    self.send_keys(self.password)
    self.loginFieldElement.click()

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a flaw in your design.

The reason your script is failing because when you create the object of login page the **init** gets called but it fails to find the driver since it is defined in the setup fn (which is never called)

Ideally in the page object model you should initialize your browser(driver) in your test file and then while creating a object of any page file you should pass that driver.

Your setup should look something like this,

Page file:

```
# setup() fn not needed here
.
.
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    emailFieldElement  = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.emailFieldID)
    passFieldElement   = self.driver. find_element_by_id(self.passFieldID)
    loginFieldElement  =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.loginButtonXpath)
.
# teardown() not needed here, should be in test file
.
```

Test File:

```
.
.
    class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

      def test_valid_login(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()   # the first 2 stmts can be in a setupclass
        self.driver.get("http://www.testaaa.com")
        log_in = LoginPage.LoginPage(self.driver)
        log_in.userLogin_valid()
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue a couple of times and every time I found it due to a mismatch between my Chrome browser version and the Chrome Webdriver version.

So, in your Chrome browser check Help>About Google Chrome before downloading a corresponding ChromeDriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/.

Good luck!